# HTTP ERROR 404 while accessing /solr/admin/ping. Reason: Not Found in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: solr, solarium

Installed SOLR 7.3.0 in ubuntu 16.04, i am able to access solr link (http://localhost:8983/solr) in browser. But admin link(http://localhost:8983/solr/admin/ping) are giving 404 error.
Permissions given to /var/solr/data, still i have problem.

Answer (score 2):

i have missed out config procedure now i am getting successful ping response using the solarium with symfony.

Created core from http://localhost:8983/solr(Core Admin > Add Core ) as "gettingstarted"

```
    use Solarium\Core\Client\Client;

    $config = [
        'endpoint' => [
            'localhost' => [
                'host' => 'localhost',
                'port' => 8983,
                'path' => '/solr/gettingstarted',
            ]
        ]
    ];
    echo "<pre>";
    $client = new Client($config);

    // create a ping query
    $ping = $client->createPing();

    // execute the ping query
    try {
        $result = $client->ping($ping);
        echo 'Ping query successful';
        echo '<br/><pre>';
        var_dump($result->getData());
        echo '</pre>';
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo 'Ping query failed';
        print_r($e);
        die;
    }
    die;
```